# L298N, HC-05 Simple Bluetooth remote car not running in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, hc-05, l298n

Arduino board type used in this session is Arduino Uno R3 DIP/SMD CH340

Below is the description of wiring and code in Arduino to assemble a Bluetooth RC car using android smartphone:

1. Tested the motor dc result both of wheel works (can spin forward and or backward). power direct from the battery.
2. Tested HC-05 bluetooth moduled. The phone can paired the bluetooth module.
3. Tested out1 out2 out3 and out4 on L298N using direct power from the battery the wheel spinning (forward and or backward).
4. The code for the Bluetooth rc simple car used below as described.

The car failed to move (forward, backward, turn left/right). how to make the motor dc and or the motor stepper works remotely. thank you

[image: Wiring Table]

[image: L298N Motor Stepper / Driver Motor]

[image: HC-05 Bluetooth module]

[image: Pin to Arduino]

[image: Fritzing Skematic]
    #include 
    SoftwareSerial mySerial(12, 13); // RX, TX
    #define m1 3
    #define m2 5
    #define m3 9
    #define m4 10

```
int data=0,kec=0;
boolean forward=true;


int fast[11]={0,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,255};

void setup()
{
  pinMode(m1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(m2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(m3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(m4,OUTPUT);

  mySerial.begin(9600);
 }

void motorOut(unsigned char lpwm, unsigned char rpwm, boolean arrow){
   if(arrow==false){
      digitalWrite(m3,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m1,LOW);
      analogWrite(m4,255-lpwm);
      analogWrite(m2,rpwm);
   }
   else{
     digitalWrite(m3,LOW);
     digitalWrite(m1,HIGH);
     analogWrite(m4,lpwm);
     analogWrite(m2,255-rpwm);
  }
}

void loop(){
  if(mySerial.available()>0){
    data=mySerial.read();
    if (data =='0') { kec=0;}
      else if (data =='1') { kec=1;}
        else if (data =='2') { kec=2;}
          else if (data =='3') { kec=3;}
            else if (data =='4') { kec=4;}
             else if (data =='5') { kec=5;}
              else if (data =='6') { kec=6;}
                else if (data =='7') { kec=7;}
                  else if (data =='8') { kec=8;}
                    else if (data =='9') { kec=9;}
                      else if (data =='q') {kec=10;}

  //S= Stop
 if (data == 'S')
 { motorOut(0,0,false); }

//F=Forward
if (data=='F')
{ motorOut(fast[kec],fast[kec],true); }

//I=turn right forward
if (data=='I')
{ motorOut(fast[kec],((fast[kec])/2),true);}

//G=turn left forward
if (data=='G')
{ motorOut(((fast[kec])/2),fast[kec],true); }

//R=turn right
if(data=='R')
{ motorOut(fast[kec],0,true); }

//L=turn left
if(data=='L')
{ motorOut(0,fast[kec],true); }

//B=back
if(data=='B')
{ motorOut(fast[kec],fast[kec],false); }

//H=turn left back
 if (data=='H')
   { motorOut(((fast[kec])/2),fast[kec],false); }

//turn right back
   if (data=='J')
    { motorOut(fast[kec],((fast[kec])/2),false); }
  }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: what tests have you done?

Comment: Instead of writing many `if`-`else if` statements, use a simple `switch(data){ case '0':`

Comment: What data gets send to `mySerial`? Can you confirm, that the correct data is actually received? Maybe echo it back to the source. If this doesn't work, your serial connection doesn't work (maybe because the HC-05 isn't really connected). If it works, try to drive the motor through the driver, by connecting the corresponding pins to 5V. If this doesn't work, your driver connection is not correct. You should provide a schematic instead of photos.

Comment: nothing displayed data from serial monitor.
HC-05, icon indicator green in android phone (success conecting to the car).
L298N, the motor run after i give direct power to PIN 5 and Ground.
the battery 4 x 1.2 alkaline or 9v

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sorry for my careless. finaly its works....wrong pin assign the main problem....should be IN1, IN2, IN4 and IN3 not IN1, IN2, IN3 and IN4. thank you for all hands for help before